# Datatable null rows

Tags: c#

I was trying to insert values from my datatable to database which was working fine until I added this piece of code to remove null values from it. Now nothing is being added so I presume all rows are getting deleted or is there something wrong with the loop...please help. I also tried `DBNull` but same effect

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((dt.Rows[i][2]).ToString()))
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
if(dt.Rows[i][2]==System.DBNull.Value)
```

instead of `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((dt.Rows[i][2]).ToString()))`

Also, you are not adding any rows in the code snippet included in your question.

Hope this may help. Regards,

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,